# In Thirst, why do Sang-hyeon and Tae-ju need the camera to watch the street outside their window?

Tags: thirst

While watching [Thirst (2009)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0762073/?ref_=nm_knf_i1), at approximately 1 hour and 40 minutes into the movie, we see that Sang-hyeon and Tae-ju have set a camera at their window to watch the street outside their apartment, like so:

[image]

They have it connected to a TV inside the apartment, but they barely even look at it.

What was the purpose of this camera? Why did they set it up there?